# Center content with Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

So, I have this code

```
<div class="featurette">
            <img class="featurette-image pull-right" src="img/BreadBakersGuildLogo.jpg">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Justin</h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    Stuff about Justin
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>Stuff about contacts</li>
                    <li>Stuff</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Unfortunately, the text under text-center isn't centered.  It appears to be a little to the left.  I also made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mPJ83/1/) fiddle to demonstrate what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is:

You are using `.container` for `<body>` which has a `width: 940px` and `p` has a `display: block` and it is rendering with reference to the 940px.

One solution would be, to use `.container{ width: 100%}`, as you might run into this issue at a later point of time too.

Comment: Unless you absolutely need container, just get rid of the class from `body`